# Javafx move specific node to front of AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

This seems like a simple question but I haven't yet been able to find a relevant answer.

I'm creating a simple Javafx application and creating nodes on click that can be dragged around.

I want to make sure a specific type of Node (Circle) is always drawn on top of the AnchorPane.

I think this is all the relevant code, but I can include the rest if needed.

How can I achieve this behavior?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    root = new AnchorPane();
    scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
    scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Shapes");
    stage.show();

}
```

**Event Handler**

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        switch (eventName) {
        case ("MOUSE_PRESSED"):
            getCurrentShape(clickPoint);
            if (!shapeSelected) {
                if (clickType.equals("SECONDARY")) { // Draw a Square
                    ShapeComponent newShape = ShapeGenerator.generateRandomSquare(clickPoint);
                    components.add(newShape);
                    root.getChildren().add(newShape.getShape());
                } else if (clickType.equals("PRIMARY")) { // Draw a Circle
                    ShapeComponent newShape = ShapeGenerator.generateCircle(clickPoint);
                    components.add(newShape);
                    /* MOVE NODE TO FRONT */
                    root.getChildren().add(newShape.getShape());
                }
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here.

I thought of this a different way. Instead of always moving the circle to the front when it's drawn, I can always move the squares to the back when they are drawn.

This will add the new shape (square) to the `AnchorPane`and then we can get the index of the most recent item (the square just drawn) and move that to the back.

```
root.getChildren().add(newShape.getShape());
root.getChildren().get(root.getChildren().size() - 1).toBack(); // Move Square to back of AnchorPane
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments.

```
root.getChildren().add(0, newShape.getShape());
```

Comment: This can be done more efficiently in a single statement: `root.getChildren().add(0, newShape.getShape());`

Comment: @fabian Thanks for the suggestion, updated my answer.